# Override default lib type in ambient declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I'm currently trying to add ambient TypeScript declarations (`.d.ts`) to a plain JS library that is intended to be used in non-TS environments.

These declarations are imported with the special `/// <reference path="app.d.ts" />` directive.
This conveniently enables code completion even in code bases where TypeScript is not directly used (due to the LSP TypeScript integration available in most IDEs).

My JS library has a declaration for a global class named `Partial` but because it collides with the [`Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), it results in an error and the editor refuse to autocomplete it.

For clarity, here is how my class ambient declaration looks like:

```
declare class Partial {
  constructor(data?: { [key:string]: any })
}
```

Every other declaration works as expected - the editor provide the auto completion and docs on hover.

The only solution I could find was to add `/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>` and it works, but this disables the code completion for the default js types (array, strings, etc.).

Is there a way to override/disable concrete types from the default TS library to avoid types conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround inspired from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594#issuecomment-566836640.

```js
interface PartialAlias { ... }

declare const Partial: {
  new(data?: { [key:string]: any }): PartialAlias;
};
```